# FabricJS canvas on top of another FabricJS canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am new to canvas. I am wondering if I can take a Fabric JS canvas and put it on time of an existing Fabric JS canvas? If so, I would I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Canvas backgrounds are transparent by default, so you are able to overlap them as layers. Use CSS to put the `canvas` elements exactly on top of each other.

Make sure, when clearing the top canvas, you use `clearRect` and not `fillRect` with a background color (even white), as that would remove the transparency and hide the other canvas.